# Происхождение слова "ананас"

Tags: этимология

Откуда в русском языке взялось слово "ананас"? По-английски будет pineapple, совсем иначе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-английски, действительно, pineapple. Но в русский язык слово ананас пришло не из английского, а из нем. Ananas или франц. ananas, которое происходит через португ. ananas из языка тупи (Бразилия) anana (по данным словаря Фасмера).